# Creating a dynamic URL for an external link inside content

Tags: customization, menus

I run the website [hightowerlowdown.org](https://hightowerlowdown.org). We use an external CRM for email and donation management (SalsaLabs), and I'd like to be able to take advantage of some of the tagging features available within. On all salsalab URLs, for example, I can append "&tag=article" and Salsa will tag the action taken for me.

What I'm trying to achieve is to tag those Salsa actions with keywords based on the type of content the user is viewing on the Wordpress website. A use case:

1. User lands on a podcast entry. The url contains /podcast/ in it.
2. That user decides to make a donation. On that podcast entry, the URL directing the user to the Salsa contribution page contains "&tag=podcast".

versus

1. User lands on an Article. The url contains /article/ in it.
2. That user decides to make a donation. On that Article, the URL directing the user to the Salsa contribution page contains "&tag=article".

Basically, I want Wordpress to say, "Hey, we've landed on [this type of content]. When I write the URL in the navigation menu code, I will attach the tag for [this type of content]."

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Where do you want to capture this data? I would suggest using something external like Google Tag Manager with Google Analytics - you can trigger events (like event = "Opened podcast") and then see which of those also donated.

Comment: @WebElaine Oh man, I didn't even think of GTM. YES. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for Google Tagmanger Event tracking and google analytics Goals.

I would refer you to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en

You can make events happen conditionally via URL or actual interaction with page elements via class or ID.

Analytics goals will allow you easily track the outcomes in GA.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't even think of GTM. YES. Thank you!

Comment: Google tag manger is great right :) and you're welcome.